# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file . Python, Django , Boto3

Tags: python, django, boto3

I have a post method in my views.py :

```
 def post(self, request):
    author = User.objects.get(id=request.data.get('user_id'))
    new_article = Article.objects.create(author=author, title=request.data.get('title'), 
                        text=request.data.get('text'),img=File(request.data.get('image[0]')))
    new_article.save()
    for i in range(20):
        img_key = 'image[{}]'.format(i)
        img = request.data.get(img_key)
        if img:
            article_img = ArticleImage(article=new_article,img=File(img), is_main=False )
            article_img.save()
        else :
            break
    images = ArticleImage.objects.filter(article=new_article)   

    return Response({
            'article': ArticleSerializer(new_article, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data                
    })
```

It creates a new article which contains img files. The image files I save in AWS S3 bucket . Saving main image of article using  **new_article.save()** method works fine , but  **article_img.save()** returns an error:

**File "C:\Users\Arcvi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\storages\backends\s3boto3.py", line 520, in _save_content
    content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)*

***ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.****

I guess I do something wrong in my for loop. If you need more information about code , I will share it . Please any help.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you get the error if you change the `for` loop to: `for i in range(1, 20):`

Comment: It works <3 , hahaha what a magic?

Comment: Yeah I think the issue is that when you save the `Article` with `image[0]`, the backend storage closes off the file. So when you then try and save the same `image[0]` for the `ArticleImage`, it falls over. Perhaps a workaround would be to make an in-memory copy of the file before saving the `Article`?

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe to open this file and then create django File object.

```
img = request.data.get(img_key)
if img:
    with open(img.file.seek(0), "rb") as opened_image:
        article_img = ArticleImage(article=new_article,img=File(opened_image), is_main=False )
        article_img.save()
```

Comment: It returns an error :**File "C:\Users\Arcvi\Desktop\djreact2\articles\api\views.py", line 47, in post
    with open(File(img), "rb") as opened_image:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not File**

Comment: Show me type of your img variable, like this: `print(type(img))`. I suppose it is File object? If it is, then try: `with open(img.file, "rb") as opened_image:`

Comment: Like what??? They are images of JSON data ,which I get from frontend . Their type is InMemoryUploadedFile .With method File(img) I parse them into file objects

Comment: open(img.file, "rb"): TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

Comment: Ok, try this: `with open(img.file.seek(0), "rb") as opened_image:`.

Comment: @AleksandrKholiavskyi  `img` is already an open file, not a path. Django opens the file for you.

Comment: It returns AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute '_committed'. Thank you so much for your responses, but I already have found the issue . (see the comments under my question)

Answer (score 0):

This might sound obvious but

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Means the file you are working with has closed. If it's a Python PIL image, you can run `yourimage.verify()`.

Once you save (ex: `new_article.save()`), files become closed. Ex: `new_article.img.closed` equals `True`.

This happened to me when overriding a Django ModelForm save method. I overcame it by setting commit equals `False`. The file will stay opened until you finally save.